# Can't find QGIS project

Tags: qfield

I have a question which has been asked before. I've been using QField very successfully on an android tablet, but have bought a new one and can't open a project, although it is in the same place as in the earlier tablet - Android/data/ch.opengis.qfield/files. On the tablet I cannot find the Android directory. The new tablet is a Samsung S2 8 inch with Android 7.0

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Which duplicate question are you referring to?

Comment: Worth checking that you haven't transferred the project into a very similar looking directory but on the SD card as there will be a "...Android/data/ch.opengis.qfield/files" folder in there too? Has tricked me before! On your device go to your highest level folder and scroll down until you see a folder something like "sdcard" or "extsd..." etc. and then follow the same directory path as you followed above.